# Securing .so file access permissions

Tags: encryption, android, mobile, c

I work for a place that offers an encryption suite for Android apps in the form of a `.so` C library to be integrated in Android apps.

The issue is that there are only two exported functions in the `.so` library: an `encrypt` function and a `decrypt` function. From what I know, one can simply call those two exported functions from **any** environment, not just our apps.

The idea here is to protect the encryption/decryption mechanism. Assuming that static analysis won't be possible, is there a way to make sure  the `.so` library can **only** run from our apps?

Comment: In cryptography, you protect the keys, not the algorithm or the implementation. So store the keys in a keystore and don't worry about who gets access to the .so.

Comment: I'm not confused. What does you're encryption suite do? Why do you use a static key instead of generating one securely on first use and storing it in the keystore? And do you use the same key in every .so that you ship?

Comment: @Solidak So every user that installs the app gets the same key? What's the point of encrypting then?

Comment: @Solidak - you're question is not a security question. It sounds like it belongs on the Android site.

Comment: make .a and include into the app

Comment: @Soidak is you shared lib "a secret code", you can use obfuscation technic. Other alternative is using Trust Zone with encrypted task, but it is much complicated, may be even not feasible on your devices.

Comment: @Soidak, I see here two problems. First you don't want other apps to call your "secret APIs". Second you don't want others to be able reverse engineer your "secret APIs". If you generate .a and build with your APP. It creates a barrier of usage your lib APIs. It becomes part of your APP. If you also obfuscate your "secret code". It makes more difficult for reverse engineering. Just find some sw to do it.

Comment: @Solidak, purpose of Trust Zone is to run an authorized code. The code is sign with let's say for example with RSA key. It also can be encrypted.  The whole infrastructure should support it. All started with secured boot, which verifies Secured OS, which mages running your Trusted App. Read more, a lot fun. We use it in our SoCs.

Comment: @solidak your edits removed the actual question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ignore reverse engineering threat (you shouldn't), you can hide the encrypt/decrypt functions of your SO, and only let them be used from a trusted environment (see `JNI_OnLoad()`). E.g. you can check the package name of the application that loads your library. But just the same, you can run same checks in your encrypt() and decrypt().

Another trick is not to use the normal packaging process for the library, but unpack it manually from your APK to some location that can only be accessed from your application. This protection will not help on rooted devices. *Update 2020*: this trick won't work on Android API 29+ (a.k.a. Android 10), which revoked execution permissions from all writable directories.

Comment: Alex, the shared lib is not written to be used by TEE. Advice to check who is using the lib seems useful.

Comment: The "bad" application can just call JNI_OnLoad with the same package name.

Comment: @user253751 no, it can not. Native code can know exactly which application runs it, and check that its is signed correctly. Again, this does not protect the native code itself from reverse engineering. Mostly, anti-debugging techniques that will help you against such threat, are generic and not Android-specific.

Comment: @AlexCohn Native code can also trick other native code into thinking it's a different application or that it's not being debugged. Worst case, they can just replace your checks with NOPs (and your signing check too).

Comment: It's easy to prepare such trick if you know exactly how the library is defended. But if you have enough reverse engineering expertise to uncover this, you could go straight for the actual algorithm of _encode()_ and _decode()_, and reimplement these instead of breaking through the defenses to call the original implementation.